# reading student record from file

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a file that has student record(first name, last name, and grade).
I have written a simple code to accomplish this task but the code fails after reading two lines from the text file. Here is my code:

```
public class Student {
private final  String first,last;
final int MAXGRADE = 100; 
final int LOWGRADE = 0; 
private final int grade;

public Student(String firstname,String lastname, int grade){
    this.first = firstname;
    this.last = lastname;
    this.grade = grade;

}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return first + " " + last + "\t" + grade;
}
}
```

and the driver has this code

```
public class driver {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
   String first_name ,last_name;
    int grade;
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("data1.txt"));
    while (fileInput.hasNextLine())
    {
        first_name = fileInput.next();
        last_name = fileInput.next();
        grade = fileInput.nextInt();

        Student st = new Student(first_name, last_name,grade);

      System.out.println(st);

    }
}
}
```

the compiler is pointing to this

```
grade = fileInput.nextInt();
```

as the source of the error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This is not how you use a Scanner. the method `nextXXX` will take the full String until the next delimiter (`"\n"`) and parse it. So in your will loop you actually take 3 lines for one student

Comment: Ideally, you should wrap your execution code in a `try catch` block so you should be able to see the full error stack.

Comment: In what format are you storing the details in your input file? It would be better if you could post a sample format of your input file.

Comment: Maryann Sandoz 50
Elois Kloss 67  
Greg Mcmillen 89 
Madelyn Derosa 45  
Piper Casella 90  -- that's the input file
Tamekia Soper 87  
Carie Hibner 79  
Ermelinda Cain 68  
Venice Schimmel 89  
Genie Merkle 81

Comment: @AxelH each line represents a single student first, last name and grade.

Comment: If each line represents single student's record, then read the complete line first and then break it and save the details to fields. There is a method in `Scanner` class called `readLine()`. You can use that.

Comment: if you have control over the format of the input file than it could be helpfull to split the fields using semi-colon etc. Only in a perfect world are persons with one first and one last name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Java 8**, then functional way of doing this would be:

```
String filePath = "C:/downloads/stud_records.txt"; // your file path
        /*
         * Gives you a list of all students form the file
         */
        List<Student> allStudentsFromFile = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).map(line -> {
            String[] data = line.split("\\s+"); //Split on your delimiter
            Student stud = new Student(data[0], data[1], Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
            return stud;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note:** I've made an assumption that this:

> **FirstName LastName Grade**

is the input file format.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me. Make Sure

1. The location of text file correctly given,
2. Integer value given at 3rd position in each line  (like:- steve smith 22)

Comment: The given code is perfect, It will read from file as expected, It is automatically delimeted by  white space(the strings and integer). One thing is you should give the text file in correct form.

Comment: You are right, not about the file since he would have and exception before the read but for the parse.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment you post "*@AxelH each line represents a single student first, last name and grade"* we can see the problem.

Your actual loop to read a line

```
while (fileInput.hasNextLine())
{
    first_name = fileInput.next();
    last_name = fileInput.next();
    grade = fileInput.nextInt();

    Student st = new Student(first_name, last_name,grade);

  System.out.println(st);

}
```

Is reading 3 lines, one per `fileInput.nextXXX();`. What you need to do is

- Read a line as a `String` : `String line = fileInput.nextLine();
- Split that line base on the delimiter : `String[] data = line.split(" "); //Or your delimiter if not space (carefull with some names...)
- Set the value from this array (parse are need for integer)

EDIT :

I have made a mistake since I am used to use `nextline` and not `next`, I can't delete the answer as it is accepted so I will update it to be more correct without changing the content.

The code is indeed correct, `next` will take the following input until the next delimiter, `\\p{}javaWhitespace}+`, but using the given solution would give you more solution to manage composed names as it could be `Katrina Del Rio 3`.